# VSCodeの設定に「javahome」及び「setting.jsonで編集」が表示されない

Tags: java, windows, vscode, windows-10

動画投稿サイトやwebサイトを参考にしながら、Windows10の環境で、VSCodeによるJavaの開発環境の構築をしているのですが、
「ファイル」から「ユーザー設定」へ行き、「設定」の検索欄でjavahomeを検索しても、
「setting.jsonで編集」が表示されません。他の設定から「setting.jsonで編集」へ行き、
「java.home」と入力しても、適したテンプレートの予測が表示されず、文字も青くなりません。
自身で確認できることが、

・jdk-17.0.1のインストールは出来ている
・環境変数変数に JAVA_HOME と C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1 は追加済み
・Pathに　%JAVA_HOME%\bin　を追加済み
・再起動後、コマンドプロンプトで java -versionを入力すると、"17.0.1"と返ってくる
・VSCodeの拡張機能から「Extension Pack for Java」をダウンロード、及びインストール済み
・動画やwebで多く紹介されているVSCodeの拡張機能である、「Java Extension Pack」は現在、
　そのままの名称では存在しておらず、「Extension Pack for Java」と名称を変えている

設定の検索欄にjavahomeと入力して、ちゃんとjsonファイルの編集が出来るようになるには、
何の工程が抜けているのか、そもそも今の環境では動画の情報が古すぎるのでしょうか。
何かしらヒントを頂けませんでしょうか。
回答お待ちしております。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: VSCodeのDocsだと現在はこの辺になって設定内容が変わっているのかもしれません。[Java extensions for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/extensions), [Installing and setting up a Java Development Kit (JDK)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial#_installing-and-setting-up-a-java-development-kit-jdk), [Configure Runtime for Projects](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_configure-runtime-for-projects)

Comment: 具体的に発生している問題は何でしょうか？(`javahome`の設定が必要だと考えられているのはなぜですか？)具体的に何を見て作業されているのか示していただけると回答しやすいです。 / 環境変数`JAVA_HOME`の設定は[自動で認識されているはずです](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java#java-tooling-jdk)ので、現在の設定のままで利用可能ではありませんか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントの内容や、そのリンク先を参考にさせて頂きつつ、VSCode内のJavaDevelopmentのチュートリアルに沿いJDKのインストールを行った結果、現状でもVSCode上でのjavaファイルの作成やコンパイル、実行が可能になりました。コメントで指摘して頂いた通り、設定の追加は不要だったようです。当初参考にしていた情報通りの工程を踏めなかったことで、混乱してしまいました。申し訳ありません。
コメントして下さった皆様、ありがとうございました。